# Can't Connect To A Telnet Server From Node.js

Tags: node.js, networking, telnet

I have a telnet server embedded in a C++ app that I can connect to with no problem
using telnet.

I want to write a node application that will connect to my server and I have tried
this

```
var net = require('net');

var port = 6502
var host = '127.0.0.1'

var socket = net.connect(port,host, function() {
    console.log("Sending data");
    socket.write("hello\r\n")

    socket.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log("received data");
        console.log( data.toString() );
        socket.end();
    })
})

socket.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(err);
})
```

Unfortunately what I get back is this

```
> node test.js
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

What's really odd is if I set up a simple echo server with node everything works
fine. Here's the working echo server code:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
  socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(6502, '127.0.0.1');
```

and from that I get

```
Sending data
received data
Echo server
hello
```

Is there any reason why:

- I can telnet into my app fine
- I can connect from node to my node echo server on the same port
- I get a connection refused if I connect from my node app to my app

### Extra Info

- On OSX (mavericks)
- Node version 0.10.28
- Telnet server in C++ is provided via embedded lua and luasocket (lua 5.1)

Comment: What is the `telnet` command line you're using when you successfully connect to the C++ telnet server?

Comment: rlwrap telnet localhost 6502

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved!

The issue is the code in my app server was binding to localhost and by default
that binds to the IPV6 address of ::1

Passing a host of localhost to net.connect assumes IPV4 and doesn't work.

The mac command line telnet and nc both work fine with this and connect correctly.

Two solutions:

- App binds to 127.0.0.1 and localhost in node works fine
- Set host address to ::1 in test.js and it connects via ipv6

All fixed now though :)

gaz

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to tell the server to listen in your code. It throws a connection refused error because there is nothing to connect to...

Add this at the end: `server.listen(port);`

Comment: I'm not trying to create a server that listens. I'm trying to connect from node to a server that's already running and works fine with command line telnet

Answer (score 0):

The prototype for net.connect is (options, callback)
See http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_connect_options_connectionlistener

I would then suggest to test your code against a standard telnet server to see how it behaves, and finally I would strongly recommend the use of jshint or jslint.

Comment: net.connect is polymorphic, net.connect(port, [host], [connectListener]) also works. Scroll down a bit on the page you linked to :)